# /admin area and /api in not loading after adding react on my .net core web application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My react website routing is cached in the browser and all the website requests are processed by this cached routing.

All requests to /admin area and /api are are not working (redirecting to react web site home page) until I do a hard refresh (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>).

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with React.
/admin area is a standard ASP.NET Core MVC.